# Jmeter threads not starting in remote VM while using Ultimate Thread Group

Tags: jmeter, distributed-testing

I have setup a primary and 1 remote VM to do distributed testing in jmeter.

For testing sanity, I setup a jmeter thread group on the primary with 10 threads and did Run -> Remote Start All from the primary and all went fine (Was able to verify 20 threads. Also, CPU usage was seen on both primary and remote)

But when I do the same with my actual test (which uses ultimate thread group), I see only the threads starting in my primary even though the message "Starting the test on host " is printed in the remote VM.
Also, there is no CPU usage seen in the remote VM.

Is this because of the Ultimate Thread Group?

I searched in google/jmeter docs, but I am not able to find any relevant compatibility matrix.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Primary" (also known as "master" in JMeter terms) doesn't generate any load, it only sends the .jmx test plan to the "remote" (also known as "slave" in JMeter terms) and collects results from there.

If your test containing [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) doesn't start most probably you don't have this Ultimate Thread Group plugin installed on the slave. This applies to any other plugins and/or dependency .jars which are in your "primary" [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

So either install Ultimate Thread Group onto "remote" machine using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager) and restart JMeter process or just copy your whole JMeter installation from "primary" to "remote" machine to avoid any collisions.

If it doesn't help - check [jmeter-server.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) on the "remote" machine and just in case on "primary" machine

Running JMeter in GUI mode is discouraged, GUI should be used only for tests development and debugging, when it comes to test execution [you must be using command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri. Your pointer to the jmeter-server.log helped identify my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Putting it here in case someone else faces similar issues with Jmeter distributed testing.

My issue was not because of the ultimate thread group but because of difference in CSV dataset config path (which was different in the primary and the secondary nodes).
My issue was resolved once I created a symlink in my secondary so that the path was similar on both nodes.